# Markers disappear when I add `clusterer` to them. @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I'm trying to use `MarkerClustererF` from [`@react-google-maps/api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) to cluster markers.

My render looks like this:

```
<MarkerClustererF>
    {(cluster) => (
      <>
        {deliveryPendingPositions.map((position, index) => {
          return (
            <MarkerF position={position} key={index} clusterer={cluster} />
          );
        })}
      </>
    )}
</MarkerClustererF>
```

My `deliveryPendingPositions` has the following format:

```json
[
    {
      lat: 46.545022,
      lng: 15.653008,
    },
    {
      lat: 46.547034,
      lng: 15.660935,
    }
]
```

My markers work normally if I don't add the `clusterer` props to them, but as soon as I add it my markers disappear and no clusterers appear.

Without `clusterer`:

[image]

With `clusterer`:

[image]

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Why do my markers disappear and why can't I see any marker clusterers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MarkerClustererF` doesn't work well with Next.js in strict mode.

Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/3150) on GitHub.